# How do I properly configure ng from npm as a normal CLI command?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I am seeing tutorials with NPM and Node.js that have the ng package handler. However, they run this straight from the command prompt. I am curious if I am missing something to install to run commands like `ng serve` for example, without having to preface them with `npm run` like `npm run ng serve --open` ?

Thank you!

Comment: To use ng , install angular cli    https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: Note that you will be using the cli only for Angular 2+ versions. If you want something for angularjs there is a [non official cli](https://github.com/SwiftySpartan/Angular-1.5-cli) and it's only for component generation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't naturally prefix the `ng server` with `npm run`

Install the angular-cli **globally**

```
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

Then you will be able to do:

```
ng serve
ng new [appname]
ng generate component [name]
```

Without any prefix and from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to install @angular/cli globally. Some projects will use different version of angular@cli and executing ng commands will have unexpected result.

Instead, install locally into dev dependencies with:

```
npm install --save-dev angular@cli
```

or Yarn:

```
yarn add --dev angular@cli
```

After you install locally, you can setup various npm scripts to execute `ng` commands:

```
scripts: {
    "dev": "ng serve"
}
```

Run the script:

```
npm run dev
```

** Please note, if you have globally installed angular@cli, running the commands mentioned above will use the local angular@cli package from node_modules/.bin.

Also, npx is a tool intended to help round out the experience of using packages from the npm registry. You can read about it more [here](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b)

Comment: you don't really need to add dev task. `npm run ng -- serve` would work just fine... To open browser `npm run ng -- server --open`

Comment: If I was payed by the keystroke I would do that